# Coordinates of rectangle annotation varies for the same location in other similar pages in PDFTron WebViewer

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

We are trying to create rectangle annotation to  highlight some text in a page (form) based on supplied coordinates. While using the same coordinates to create rectangle annotation for the same text in same location in other similar pages, the annotation is getting created somewhere else instead of the desired text location. These issue may be because of the offset difference in the pages as we are suspecting. Is there any way to resolve this issue? Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

I am using below code to create rectangle annotation over a text based on  supplied coordinates (hardcoded here just for example)

```
var docViewer = readerControl.docViewer;
var am = docViewer.GetAnnotationManager();
// Create Rectangle over text with coordinates

var rectAnnot = new Annotations.RectangleAnnotation();
    rectAnnot.X = (644); 
    rectAnnot.Y = (736);
    rectAnnot.Width = (125); 
    rectAnnot.Height = (15);
    rectAnnot.NoMove = true;
    rectAnnot.NoResize = true;
    docViewer.ZoomTo(1.5, 644, 736);

    rectAnnot.PageNumber = 1;
    rectAnnot.Author = this.currUser;
    rectAnnot.FillColor = new Annotations.Color(255, 255, 0);
    rectAnnot.StrokeColor = new Annotations.Color(255, 0, 0);
    rectAnnot.StrokeThickness = 1;
    rectAnnot.Opacity = 0.5;
    am.AddAnnotation(rectAnnot);
```

Now by using the same coordinates to create the same annotation in other similar forms having different margins/offset, the annotation is placed elsewhere instead of placing over the same text located in the same location as it is in the previous form.